# Socket chat application cannot connect

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to create a chat application in Python using sockets. I am not able to connect the (HOST, PORT) pair.

This is the GUI code snippet and the error is seen in the line `client_socket.connect(ADDR)`:

```
root = Tk()
root.title("Kchat V1.0")
mainScreenlabel = Frame(root)
mainScreenlabel.pack()
mainScreeninput = Frame(root)
mainScreeninput.pack(side=BOTTOM)
HOST = StringVar()
titleLabel = Label(mainScreenlabel, text="Welcome to Kchat!!")
inputLabel = Label(mainScreeninput, text="Host IP :")
inputEntry = Entry(mainScreeninput, textvariable=HOST)
connectButton = Button(mainScreeninput, text="Connect", command=connect)
titleLabel.pack()
inputLabel.pack(side=LEFT)
inputEntry.pack(side=LEFT)
connectButton.pack()
PORT = 33000
BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(ADDR)

receive_thread = Thread(target=receive)
receive_thread.start()
root.mainloop() #Starts GUI execution
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Tracebak (most recent call last):
    File".\chatClient.py", line 76, in <module>
      client_socket.connect(ADDR)

TypeError: str, bytes or bytearray expected, not StringVar
```

Comment: please post your code and error messages as text. at least i'm not going to click on any images for such information.

Comment: As it looks, `HOST` is a `tkinter` variable and not a `str` or `bytearray`. You need to set the `HOST`'s value using `HOST.set(<hostname>)`. For more, read [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm).

Comment: @VasilisG.: I see your edit was approved, but I would have REJECTED it. Inlining images of code is not an improvement.

Comment: @usr2564301 fixed it.

Comment: @usr2564301 I made another edit in which I replaced the images with the actual code. It's still pending though.

Comment: @VasilisG.: well, thanks for taking such efforts I guess. I hope you did not make any typing errors in transcribing the images – it's one of the reasons we ask *the original poster* to do this ... ('Coz jeez, it's just copy and pasting plain text! – what's so incredibly hard to understand about that!? (And I've improved that *horrible* title as well.))

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
client_socket.connect(HOST, PORT)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a while since this was asked, but to anyone who is struggling with this:

What is actually happening here: the method for connecting to host requires a tuple of (string, int), but here it is trying to pass (StringVar, int).
Instead you should try to pass

```
host = StringVar()
ttk.Entry(frame, textvariable=host)
s.connect(host.get(), port) # using .get() method of StringVar() to retrieve the string.
```

or pass it into a function.

What is important to know is that tkinter will try to run all functions in the widgets, to stop this from happening and stop getting a lot of errors try to add lambda expressions: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions

This will make the function not return anything.